# Are there any open source libraries of C functions available for cperf and cace?

Tags: informix

INFORMIX-SQL 4.10 DD6:

I would like to create custom runners for Perform and Ace which contain several C funcs like: concat(tag1,tag2) and other useful functions which are not available in 4.10 sformbld and saceprep.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such libraries, or I'd have chipped in an answer.